# Have a gulp watch task wait for bower to complete

Tags: gulp, bower, visual-studio-2015, gulp-watch, gulp-inject

I tried creating a gulp task to watch `bower.json` so that when it changes, [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject) updates `index.html`. However, if the update requires fetching a new component from the internet, the watch task usually completes before the files come down. [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) sees no new files and `index.html` is overwritten with the same contents it had previously.

I'm using the out-of-the-box Visual Studio 2015 bower and gulp integration. That integration automatically runs bower in response to a change to `bower.json`.

How can I tell my watch task to wait until bower completes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. We can't know when bower install will be ended from another shell.

Just install needed packages and run watcher.

Answer (score 0):

One possible but not quite nice solution is to watch the bower_components directory for changes instead of bower.json. It hardly will be worth the cpu though...

I wonder why you actually need this, if you manually trigger a bower install you could easily restart your gulp watch task as well...

Comment: I updated the question to answer your question about why I want this. The reason is that I'm using the Visual Studio 2015 integration that runs bower automatically when `bower.json` changes. I'm trying to extend that behavior to get everything to update automatically when `bower.json` changes.

Comment: Regarding watching `bower_components`, the problem I see is how would the watcher know when the update is done, since several files get added with a new component, and I doubt they are using the file system's feature for transacted writes.